# Python select 5last value of an excel column

Tags: python, excel

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve the last 5 values of an excel column instead of all the values in that same column.

Currently I am able to select all the data in the column with the following piece of code:

```
var= pd.read_excel("Path/MyFile.xlsx",'MS3',skiprows=15)
xDate = list(var['Date'])
```

Is there a way to retrieve the last 5 values in this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use `tail` like `head`

```
var.tail(5)
```

Comment: Thats what I needed

Comment: great ! so can you please mark it as solved ? thx

Comment: gotta wait 6 mn

Answer (score 1):

you can simply go for this:

`xDate[-5:]`